# Highlight if it is the only cell not containing "0"

Tags: excel, excel-2010

I'm looking for a way in Excel to set up a Conditional Formatting to help identify single errors. We have an Excel spreadsheet with a row of values. If there are only errors in a single section, such as the following, it will be highlighted:

[image: highlight example]    *note, the `1` could be a `2` and still be highlighted

However, if there are multiple errors in different sections. It would not be highlighted, such as the following:

[image: Not Highlight example]

So far I haven't been able to find a solution.

***Edit in: Looks like I am on the right track now thanks to you guys. I want to try these solutions out, but I have to run at the moment. As soon as I get a second to sit down at my computer, I'll try these out and see if it works for me. I'll accept an answer then. Thanks again guys.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you want is a formula such as `=AND(COUNTIF($A1:$D1,0)=3,A1<>0)` in Conditional Formatting.

[image: SO18272522 example]

(Using Excel 2007)

Comment: You and Jerry seem to have put me on the right track. I'll try it out with my ranges, but that looks like it should work. Much simpler than I was trying to make it/

Answer (score 1):

I take it to mean that numbers other than 0 indicate an error?

You can probably use this formula in the conditional formatting:

```
=AND(A1<>0,COUNTIF($A1:$D1,"<>0")=1)
```

Assuming that the first value is in cell A1. You can change the range and cell references as necessary.

Comment: Yes, number other than 0 indicate an error. I'll try this out.

Comment: Okay then Duffie. Let me know of the outcome :)

Answer (score 1):

If all your values are zeroes or postive numbers try this formula for conditional formatting for row 2

`=AND(A2<>0,COUNTIF(2:2,">0")=1)`

you can copy to other rows or change the "applies to" range as required